# How can you get ping to print human readable timestamps?

Tags: scripting, ping

Ping can print you a timestamp on every line but its in unix date format :(

```
ping -D localhost  
PING localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
[1415629479.482938] 64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
```

I'm looking for a simple pipe command that can convert them on the fly to something like this:

```
[Sat 14 Feb 2009 01:31:30 SAST] 64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
```

Also I want it to run continuously, it shouldn't wait for the command to terminate before printing results.

Comment: UNIX time is easier to work with than structured time format

Comment: @HrvojeŠpoljar well I can't look at these unix times and know what time the pings stopped working, I'd prefer it in a human readable format

Comment: sure you can; take unix time and put it in command say... date -d '@timestamp'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036116/convert-timestamp-to-datetime-with-sed

with bit of scripting...

```
ping -D localhost | while read row 
do 
  awk '{ sub(/[0-9]{10}/, strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", substr($0,2,10))) }1' <<< "$row"
done
```

Runs as

```
$ ping -D localhost | while read row; do awk '{ sub(/[0-9]{10}/, strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", substr($0,2,10))) }1' <<< "$row" ; done
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
[2014-11-10 16:06:40.145811] 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
[2014-11-10 16:06:41.144926] 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
```

Comment: I put that in a script and replaced `localhost` with `$@`; but it prints `function strftime never defined` with mawk and empty lines with gawk. What may I be missing?

Comment: this example works with gawk. I'm not sure what you intended to do by replacing `localhost` with `$@` but if you pass multiple arguments it will likely break because ping command is expecting 1 argument for target host. Can you check if it's malfunctioning with original example which pings localhost?

Comment: Looks like it has been a c&p error. I typed it in and it works (with gawk), both with `localhost` and with `$@`. Btw I use `$@` instead of `$1` because I wanted to keep it more flexible: currently I add `-i 15` before the address.

Comment: Oh one more thing: What might be the easiest way to get rid of the microseconds part and/or `xx bytes from server.`? `str_replace` in awk or `cut`?`

Comment: use this awk `awk '{ sub(/[0-9]{10}\.[0-9]{5,8}/, strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", substr($0,2,10))) }1'` to get rid of microseconds

Answer (score 5):

I think modifying the UNIX timestamp given by `-D`, as most answers suggest, is too complicated. Why not just make your own timestamp and stick it to the front of each line:

```
ping localhost | while read l; do echo `date` $l; done
```

You may give whatever formatting options to `date`, as you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

```
ping google.com | awk '/^[0-9]+ bytes from / { "date" | getline pong; close("date"); print pong":",$0; }'
```

This comes from http://tech.jocke.no/2010/09/27/add-timestamp-to-ping/

It worked well also!

Answer (score 1):

On another server I was getting

```
awk: line 2: function strftime never defined
```

and there is no easy way to install gawk so I figured out how to do it without `awk` just with `date` (as per @Hrvoje Špoljar's hint)

```
ping -D  localhost | while read row; do 
    if [[ $row == \[*\]* ]]; then 
        echo -n \[$(date -d "@$(echo $row| sed 's/^\[//' | sed 's/\].*//')")\] ;
    fi ; 
    echo $row | sed 's/\[.*\]//' <<< "$row"; 
done
```

which yields

```
[Tue Apr 14 12:58:51 SAST 2015] 64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
```

Comment: That doesn´t seem to work with dash; throws a syntax error in line 2: `exptected conditional binary operator`, `Syntax error at unexpected word >>\[*\]*<<`. Do you have a hint?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on macOS:

```
ping -i 5 google.com | while read pong; do echo "$(date -j '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') $pong"; done
```

Adapted from the command given here: http://shawnreeves.net/wiki/index.php?title=Ping_with_timestamp_on_Mac_OS_X

The output looked like this:

```
2021-10-10 13:23:21 PING google.com (142.250.80.14): 56 data bytes
2021-10-10 13:23:21 64 bytes from 142.250.80.14: icmp_seq=0 ttl=115 time=83.045 ms
2021-10-10 13:23:26 64 bytes from 142.250.80.14: icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=39.765 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solution didn't work for me, I had to modify it a litte. Here is the version that works for me:

```
ping -D localhost | while read row; do awk '{ $1=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", substr($0,2,10));print $0}' <<< $row;done
```